# Getting NaN instead of a number in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem in the code below; getting a NaN instead of a value(number)

```
prompt("your name");
prompt("your crush's name");
var loveScore = Math.round() * 100;
loveScore = Math.floor(loveScore) + 1;
console.log(loveScore);
alert("your love score is " + loveScore + "%");
```

pls help me out with a solution

Comment: use `Math.random()`

Comment: `Math.round()` expect a number as input, i think you want to use random instead of round

Comment: `Math.round()` results in `NaN`, all following is just a consequence

Comment: If you round `undefined` then I’d expect you to get Not A Number.

Comment: Math.round() expect a number (possibly a float) and it's going empty , which makes the result NaN

Comment: As others already said, [`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) expects an argument and the function you probably wanted to use is [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).

Answer (score 1):

I think you have 2 errors:

- the function `Math.round` always needs a parameter, otherwise it will return `NaN` as it is happening.
- I think you wanted to use `Math.random()` instead of `Math.round()` doing that small change, made everything work.

```js
prompt("your name");
prompt("your crush's name");
var loveScore = Math.random() * 100;
loveScore = Math.floor(loveScore) + 1;
console.log(loveScore);
alert("your love score is " + loveScore + "%");
```